# Moq does not call correct method in inheritance tree

Tags: c#, .net-core, mocking, moq

I have framework source code, which i do not want to modify. However I need to change its behavior. I accomplish this by creating extension classes for framework's code and modifying behavior as I see fit. Having this background in mind will let you better understand what I am trying to achieve.

Framework code:

```
public interface IItem
{
    void PerformAction();
}

public class Item : IItem
{
    public IItemChild itemChild;

    public Item(IItemChild ic)
    {
        itemChild = ic;
    }

    public void PerformAction()
    {
        itemChild.PerformAction(1, c:1);
    }
}

public interface IItemChild
{
    void PerformAction(int a = 0, int b = 0, int c = 0);
}

public class ItemChild : IItemChild
{
    public virtual void PerformAction(int a = 0, int b = 0, int c = 0)
    {

    }
}
```

Framework extension code:

```
public interface IItemExtension : IItem
{

}

public class ItemExtension : Item, IItemExtension
{
    public ItemExtension(IItemChildExtension ice) : base(ice) { }
}

public interface IItemChildExtension : IItemChild
{
    void PerformAction(int a = 0, int b = 0, int c = 0);
}

public class ItemChildExtension : ItemChild, IItemChildExtension
{
    public void PerformAction(int a = 0, int b = 0, int c = 0)
    {

    }
}
```

I've also written a test class to check the behavior of extension code:

```
public class Tests
{
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var itemChildMock = new Mock<IItemChildExtension>();
        itemChildMock.Setup(mock => mock.PerformAction(1, 0, 1)).Callback(() =>
        {
            var test = 2;
        });

        var itemExtension = new ItemExtension(itemChildMock.Object);
        //itemExtension = new ItemExtension(new ItemChildExtension());
        itemExtension.PerformAction();

        var invocations = itemChildMock.Invocations;

    }
}
```

The Callback function in this code does not get triggered. Upon inspection of mock invocations I noticed that IItemChild.PerformAction(1, 0, 1) was called, even though mock is created for IItemChildExtension.

Uncommenting second assignment of itemExtension gets rid of the mock and uses a "real" implementation instead. Running this results in IItemChildExtension.PerformAction(1, 0, 1) getting called. I would like my test to execute same method that would be executed without mocks.

Why is mock invoking incorrect method? Am I missing some configuration which would result in desired behavior?

Comment: `IItemChildExtension.PerformAction` hides inherited member from `ItemChild`

Comment: I commend you for having a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that was able to be used to reproduce the problem and identify a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IItemChildExtension.PerformAction` hides inherited member from `IItemChild`

And the shown setup was done on `IItemChildExtension.PerformAction` not `IItemChild`

You will have to explicitly tell Moq which member you expect to be invoked.

```
//Arrange
var itemChildMock = new Mock<IItemChildExtension>();
itemChildMock.As<IItemChild>().Setup(mock => mock.PerformAction(1, 0, 1)).Callback(() => {
    var test = 2;
});

var itemExtension = new ItemExtension(itemChildMock.Object);
//itemExtension = new ItemExtension(new ItemChildExtension());

//Act
itemExtension.PerformAction();

var invocations = itemChildMock.Invocations;
```

Note the use of `.As<IItemChild>()` when setting up the expectation.

With the above change the test exercises as expected.

If I remove the member that was hiding the derived member

```
public interface IItemChildExtension : IItemChild {
    //void PerformAction(int a = 0, int b = 0, int c = 0);
}
```

The test, when exercised, behaves as expected without the changes originally suggested.